# mount image containing single partition

Tags: linux, image, mount

I made an image of a single partition from a disk containing multiple partitions using the following:

```
#ddrescue -d -r3 /dev/sdb3 sdb3.img sdb3.logfile
```

However, when I try to mount the image using the following:

```
mount -o loop,ro sdb3.img /media/mymount
```

I get the following error message:

```
Failed to read last sector (81919999): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
    or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
    or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
    or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
    or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).

Failed to mount '/dev/loop0': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/loop0' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Any help to resolve the issue would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: You haven't told `mount` the type of the filesystem using `-t`.

Answer (score 0):

To mount a partition from an image file you can use `kpartx`.

To list the mappings the tool detects in the image file:

```
kpartx -l sdb3.img
```

Then to add the mappings:

```
kpartx -a sdb3.img
```

The partitions will then appear as devices under `/dev/mapper`, they can then be mounted normally.

See `man kpartx` and this [blog](http://nfolamp.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/mounting-raw-image-files-and-kpartx/).

Comment: The image is **NOT that of whole disk** and that of a single partition. As far as I think, kpartx is used to mount whole disk image.

Comment: Not quite, if your whole disk image is in a file say, sdb3.img, but the partition you want to mount is inside sdb3.img, you can use kpartx. It will add the entries found in the images partition table to /dev/mapper/ and then you can mount them as you would normally

Comment: Perhaps I'm using the wrong terminology, but if the image file is the whole partition, then perhaps as pointed out by Mark Setchell in the comments you just need to specify the type, I've used kpartx successfuly to mount one or more partitions that are inside the image file. Like when you create a VM disk image and it partitions the space you give as if it were a single drive.